# Real roots for polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Is there any necessary and sufficient condition for a complex polynomial to have a real root?

A complex polynomial has a real root if and only if...?

Comment: Sufficient, yes. Necessary, probably not. (If $p$ has a real root then so does $pq$ for any complex polynomial $q$.)

Comment: Since this was not mentioned so far, note that $P$ has a real root iff the real polynomial $\gcd(P,\bar{P})$ has a real root, where $\bar{P}(z)=\overline{P(\bar{z})}$. The interest is that $\gcd$ has smaller degree (instead of $P\bar{P}$ which has twice the degree)— generically it even has degree $0$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. If your polynomial is not yet real, replace $P$ by $P\bar P$ ($\bar P$ has complex conjugated coefficients). Therefore we may suppose that $P\in{\mathbb R}[X]$.Using the Euclid algorithm, you may find the g.c.d of $P$ and $P'$. Dividing $P$ by this g.c.d, your are left with the case where $P$ is real and has simple roots.

Now, you use te Euclid algorithm : $P_0=P$, $P_1=P'$ and $P_{k-1}=Q_kP_k-P_{k+1}$. The sequence $(P_k)_k$ ends with a constant polynomial. Take $a>0$ large enough that $P$ may not have a root in $[a,+\infty)$. Let $V(a)$ be the number of sign changes in the sequence $(P_k(a))_k$. Likewise, take $b<0$ such that $P$ has no root in $(-\infty,b)$ and compute $V(b)$.

Theorem : the number of real roots of $P$ equals $V(b)-V(a)$.

Comment: This seems great, but is not a condition in terms of the coefficinets. Is there any condition obtained by the coefficients or by the discreminant of p?

Comment: Denis: what is $Q_k$? 

Comment: @Willie: I think $Q_k$ is just the quotient when $P_{k-1}$ is divided by $P_k$.

Comment: @mosen. If $P$ is quadratic, this calculation gives you the discriminant.

Answer (score 5):

This is just a bit too long for a comment :)

Let $P$ be your polynomial and $x$ its real root. Obviously, $P(x)=0$ if and only if $$Q(x)\equiv (\mathrm{Re} P(x))^2+(\mathrm{Im} P(x))^2=0.$$ Now, $Q(x)$ is a polynomial with *real* coefficients, which reduces your question to finding criteria for a *real-coefficients* polynomial to have a real root, and these are discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20946/criteria-to-determine-whether-a-real-coefficient-polynomial-has-real-root).

Comment: Why is $Q(z)$ a polynomial in $z$?

Comment: Specifically, take $P(z)=z-1$

Comment: @Yemon: $x$ is assumed to be *real*, and then my 
$Q(x)$ equals $P(x)\overline{P(x)}$ (cf. Denis' answer).

Comment: @Yemon: In fact $Q(x)=P(x)\bar P(x)$ even for complex $x$ (sorry for a poor formulation in previous comment), but, and that's the main point, for *real* $X$ $P(x)\bar P(x)$ is clearly a polynomial in $x$.

Comment: @Yemon: of course I meant for *real* $x$.

Comment: MP: OK, but then I prefer Denis' formulation. (The polynomials have complex coefficients and complex roots, I wasn't keen on your elision between the variable and the roots. So your answer is what Denis suggested, is that correct?)

Comment: Put it this way: P "is" an ordered tuple of complex numbers. Out of those, one wishes to define a new ordered tuple Q of real numbers, such that when you interpret P as a polynomial (over the complex field) then its zeros are precisely those of Q as a polynomial (with real coefficients but allowing complex roots). Is that something like what you meant?

Comment: @Yemon: That's one way to look at it, yes. 

Comment: @Yemon: provided one considers $P$ as map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ (rather than from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$), of course. But in the case under study we are interested in real roots only anyway.

Answer (score 0):

since, $P$ has a real root if and only if $p\bar{p}$ (Denis introduced this above) has. $p\bar{p}$ is a real polynomial and one can use Tarski's theorem.