# On entire functions with real and simple zeros

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials

There is a nice necessary and sufficient criterion for a polynomial $p_n$ of degree $n$ with real coefficients to have all zeros real and simple. Namely, it says: *$p_n$ has $n$ (distinct) real roots $x_{1},\dots,x_{n}$ iff the Hankel matrix
$$S_{n}=\begin{pmatrix}
 s_{0} & s_{1} & \dots & s_{n-1}\\
 s_{1} & s_{2} & \dots & s_{n}\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
 s_{n-1} & s_{n} & \dots & s_{2n-2}
    \end{pmatrix}, \quad s_{k}:=\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}^{k},$$
is positive definite; see, for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20946/criteria-to-determine-whether-a-real-coefficient-polynomial-has-real-root).*

**My first question** asks if there is some "infinite analogue" of the above equivalence where a polynomial is replaced by an entire function.

More concretely, let me assume the following. Let $f$ is a given entire function with real Taylor coefficients. Next, let $\{p_{n}\}_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of polynomials (with increasing degree) approximating $f$. For example, we may assume $p_{n}\to f$, for $n\to\infty$, uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. (One can take $p_n$ to be the truncated Taylor expansion of $f$, for instance.) Assume further that $x_{1}(n),\dots,x_{n}(n)$ are zeros of $p_n$ and that there exist limits
$$\hskip100pt \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(x_{j}(n)\right)^{k}=\alpha_{k},\hskip100pt (*)$$
for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

**The second question is**: if the Hankel matrix $A$, where $A_{i,j}:=\alpha_{i+j}$, $i,j\geq0$, is associated with a positive moment functional, i.e., all the principal sections of $A$ are positive definite, can one say something about zeros of $f$? Are they real and simple, for example?

**The third question**: Let me add one last related question. Assume that we have the sequence of polynomials $p_{n}$ as above, so the limits in $(*)$ hold, but we have no limit function $f$. The sequence $\{p_{n}\}$ is not necessarily convergent. Is it true that, if $A$ has all the principal sections positive definite, then the sequence $\{p_{n}\}$ is asymptotically real-rooted, that is, all the limit points of zeros are real?

A slight reformulation of the question as well as an addition of some other assumptions (for example, on the order of $f$, the rate of the convergence in the limits $(*)$, etc.) is possible.

Comment: I think it is related with [the Li's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%27s_criterion)

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the magic words are [Laguerre-Polya Class.](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~tom/mathfiles/iteratedLT.pdf) (the link is to an article by Tom Craven and George Csordas, which has many references.)

Comment: Thank you for the relevant keyword and the paper! I checked just quickly results of the paper and they are interesting (Section 2, in particular). Nevertheless, most part of my post still remain unanswered.