# Degree four polynomials with no real roots

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry

Consider a degree four polynomial
$$
f = a_4x^4 + a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x+ a_0 \in \mathbb{R}[x]
$$
with real coefficients. The discriminant $\Delta_f$ of $f$ is a homogeneous polynomials of degree six in the $a_i$.

If $\Delta_f > 0$ then either $f$ has four real roots or $f$ does not have any real root at all.

What conditions does one have to add to $\Delta_f > 0$ in order to characterize the degree four polynomials with no real roots?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This should work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem

Comment: There is not a unique answer to this: The locus with no real roots is one of the connected components of $\Delta_f > 0$, and there are many different inequalities which one can use to distinguish the $0$ root component from the $4$ root component. Sturm's theorem is one method. Another method is to compute the Hermite Matrix; see the top voted answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20946/criteria-to-determine-whether-a-real-coefficient-polynomial-has-real-root .

Comment: taking $a_4=1$  and no real roots it is a sum of squares of real polynomials,  although finding the coefficients may be messy. But it may be bounded below by a sum of squares that is not difficult to find.

Comment: Thank you to all of you. From Speyer's comment it seems that inside the $\mathbb{R}^5$ parametrizing degree four polynomials the locus parametrizing those with no real roots contains a semialgebraic subset of dimension 5. Is this correct?

Comment: See Fig 4.2 in https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/marie-francoise.roy/bpr-ed2-posted1.pdf above the swallowtail.